# Bash Autocomplete script that uses otherh auto completions

Tags: bash, scripts, auto-completion

Hey guys I have been searching and reading about bash completions scripts and I cant seem to find exactly what I need.

The autocomplete behaviour I am looking for is similar to the time command in ubuntu.

eg. If I type `time dock[tab]` it completes `time docker` because I have docker installed. The autocomplete will carry on for the already-completed command.
eg. If I type `time docker exec -ti [tab]` it will suggest all the docker container names as if the time command was not in front of the docker command.

Is there some way I can replicate this behaviour for my own script?

`myScript.sh docker exec -ti [tab]`